# Add worker to PM2 pool. Don't reload/restart existing workers

Tags: node.js, pm2, bull

Env.: Node.js on Ubuntu, using PM2 programmatically.

I have started PM2 with 3 instances via Node on my main code. Suppose I use the PM2 command line to delete one of the instances. Can I add back another worker to the pool? Can this be done without affecting the operation of the other workers?

I suppose I should use the `start` method:

```
pm2.start({
 name : 'worker',
 script    : 'api/workers/worker.js',         // Script to be run
 exec_mode : 'cluster',        // OR FORK
 instances : 1,                // Optional: Scale your app by 4
 max_memory_restart : '100M',   // Optional: Restart your app if it reaches 100Mo
 autorestart : true
 }, function(err, apps) {
 pm2.disconnect();
 });
```

However, if you use `pm2 monit` you'll see that the 2 existing instances are restarted and no other is created. Result is still 2 running instances.

**update**
it doesn't matter if `cluster` or `fork` -- behavior is the same.

**update 2** The command line has the `scale` option ( https://keymetrics.io/2015/03/26/pm2-clustering-made-easy/ ), but I don't see this method on the programmatic API documentation ( https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/blob/master/ADVANCED_README.md#programmatic-api ).

Answer (score 2):

I actually think this can't be done in PM2 as I have the exact same problem.

I'm sorry, but I think the solution is to use something else as PM2 is fairly limited. The lack of ability to add more workers is a deal breaker for me.

I know you can "scale" on the command line if you are using clustering but I have no idea why you can not start more instances if you are using fork. It makes no sense.

Comment: Yes. If you want to have an elastic pool of workers, scaling should be the first thing in your mind, and that should be done in programmatic way, so you can actually write code to make decisions according to server load. I'll keep the question open... hopefully this will be released soon...

Answer (score 0):

As I know, all commands of PM2 can also be used programmatically, including `scale`. Check out [CLI.js](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/blob/master/lib/CLI.js) to see all available methods.

Try to use the `force` attribute in the application declaration. If `force` is true, you can start the same script several times, which is usually not allowed by PM2 (according to the [Application Declaration
 docs](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/))

By the way, `autorestart` it's `true` by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by use of a ecosystem.config file.
Inside that file you can specify as much worker processes as you want.

E.g. we used BullJS to develop a microservice architecture of different workers that are started with the help of PM2 on multiple cores: The same worker started as named instances multiple times.

Now when jobs are run BullJS load balances the workloads for one specific worker on all available instances for that worker.

You could of course start or stop any instance via CLI and also start additional named workers via the command line to increase the amount of workers (e.g. if many jobs need to be run and you want to process more jobs at a time):

```
pm2 start './script/to/start.js' --name additional-worker-4
pm2 start './script/to/start.js' --name additional-worker-5
```